# How can I check the minor version of an nvidia driver that is not yet installed?

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, xorg

A while back I had some issues trying to install "nvidia-driver-440" - after installing the driver, I could no longer log in due to some crash in the X server.  As a result, I went with the "nvidia-driver-435" instead.  However, today I learned that I must have the 440 driver in order for software that I want to use to work properly.

I want to compare the minor version of the driver that apt-get or ubuntu-drivers would install against the sub-version of the driver that is available if I run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`.  They all have the same package name, but since they come from different sources I am hoping that latter is a newer minor version that will actually work.

How can I determine the sub-revision of the driver without installing it? If I install the same one as last time my system will be inoperable until I purge nvidia and go back to 435.

So far I tried caching the ubuntu package (`sudo apt-file update`) and then listing the files in the package (`apt-file list nvidia-driver-440`). But the package doesn't appear to have any actual driver in it, it's just documentation files in `/usr/share/doc/nvidia-driver-440/`.

For what it's worth, I need version 440.26.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `apt-cache policy (packagename)` to see the detailed package version before it is installed but after the PPA is added.

Alternatively just go to the PPA web page and scroll down. The minor version is in the package name. 
https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: oh... that's a bit confusing though, i see both 440.82 and 440.26 for `nvidia-graphics-drivers-440` as well as 440.64 for nvidia-settings. I do see by running the policy command *Before* adding the PPA that it wants to install `440.59`, which is interesting!

Comment: PPAs keep two versions. Note the codename next to the package too. Maybe you're looking at the wrong Ubuntu release?

Comment: i was looking at the web link.  after adding the PPA, it now shows 440.82, but also shows the 440.59 version from the default ubuntu location.  I assume it will install the PPA one, preferring it over the default, then?

Comment: The priority in the left column of the apt output, and the version number will dictate hat. S

Comment: i don't see a priority (left column)

Comment: It's just a number next to each package. Like 500 or 100

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108115/discussion-between-michael-and-popey).